# How to get PrimarySMTPAddress when running Get-ADPermission

Tags: powershell, active-directory, exchange-server

I would like output each user that has SendAs permission to a mailbox.  However, I would like to use the primarySMTPAddress as the identifier, which is not exposed in the Get-ADPermission cmdlet.

How can I modify this line of code to do so:

```
$SendAs = Get-ADPermission $Mailbox.DistinguishedName | ? {$_.ExtendedRights -like "Send-As" -and $_.User -notlike "NT AUTHORITY\SELF" -and !$_.IsInherited} | % {$_.User}
```

I tried with something like this but to no avail:

```
$SendAs = Get-ADPermission $Mailbox.DistinguishedName | ? {$_.ExtendedRights -like "Send-As" -and $_.User -notlike "NT AUTHORITY\SELF" -and !$_.IsInherited} | % {$_.User}
$sendAs| %{$uSendAs += ($(if($uSendAs){";"})  + (Get-mailbox $_))}
```

I am attempting to incorporate it into this script:

```
$OutFile = "C:\scripts\export.txt" 
"DisplayName" + "," + "Alias" + "," + "Primary SMTP" + "," + "Full Access" + "," + "Send As" + "," + "Send on Behalf" | Out-File $OutFile -Force 

$Mailboxes = Get-Mailbox -ResultSize:Unlimited | Select Identity, Alias, DisplayName, DistinguishedName, primarysmtpaddress 
ForEach ($Mailbox in $Mailboxes) 
{ 
       $SendAs = Get-ADPermission $Mailbox.DistinguishedName | ? {$_.ExtendedRights -like "Send-As" -and $_.User -notlike "NT AUTHORITY\SELF" -and !$_.IsInherited} | % {$_.User} 
       $FullAccess = Get-MailboxPermission $Mailbox.Identity | ? {$_.AccessRights -eq "FullAccess" -and !$_.IsInherited} | % {$_.User} 
       $sendbehalf=Get-Mailbox $Mailbox.Identity | select-object -expand grantsendonbehalfto | select-object -expand rdn | % {$_.User} 
       if (!$SendAs -and !$FullAccess -and !$sendbehalf){continue}
       $Mailbox.DisplayName + "," + $Mailbox.Alias + "," + $Mailbox.primarysmtpaddress + "," + $FullAccess + "," + $SendAs + "," + $sendbehalf | Out-File $OutFile -Append 
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Get-Recipient, as the permissions can be granted to individuals or groups. So, it would be something like:

```
Get-ADPermission $Mailbox.Identity | where { ($_.ExtendedRights -like “*Send-As*”) -and ($_.IsInherited -eq $false) -and -not ($_.User -like “NT AUTHORITY\SELF”) } | Select @{n='Identity';e={(Get-Recipient $_.Identity).PrimarySmtpAddress}}
```